# QStringList initialization does not perform as documentation describes

Tags: c++, qt6, kde-plasma

[QStringList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringlist.html#initializing)

[KFileMetaData](https://invent.kde.org/johnfreeman/kfilemetadata/-/blob/master/src/extractors/ffmpegextractor.cpp?ref_type=heads#L79) is declared in similar fashion but fails

[Job Failure on line](https://invent.kde.org/johnfreeman/kfilemetadata/-/jobs/1696882#L546)

Including the QString header expecting that deeper references to library headers would not override current file level inclusion

Job level failures are different among operating systems

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre] and [edit] your question to include enough code and data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take a look at the code a few lines up. https://invent.kde.org/johnfreeman/kfilemetadata/-/blob/master/src/extractors/ffmpegextractor.cpp?ref_type=heads#L38 and the note here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#QString-8

Comment: The goal of this site is to build a library of questions and answers that will be useful in the future. To achieve this goal, questions must not depend on links for key information. (From [Ask]: *"Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time"*) Links are acceptable for supplemental information, but they should be accompanied by summaries of the key information. A question should be answerable without following links.